# R- replace part of a string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
2014/15  All codes All admissions 
2014/15  C33-C34   All diseases which can be caused by smoking 
2014/15  C00-D48   All cancers   
2014/15  J00-J99   All respiratory diseases
2014/15  I00-I99   All circulatory diseases
```

And i want to make the year like this:

```
2014  All codes All admissions 
2014  C33-C34   All diseases which can be caused by smoking 
2014  C00-D48   All cancers   
2014  J00-J99   All respiratory diseases
2014  I00-I99   All circulatory diseases
```

How do i do that?

P.S. keep in mind that i have more years like 2015/16, 2009/10...
So basically i want to remove everything after the "/". 
Also i'm using ggplot2 and tidyverse.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also I've tried this:
admissions <- gsub (" /* ", " ", admissions$Year)

But it's not working.

Comment: `df$year <- gsub("\\/.+","",df$year)` will do it.  You need to escape the `/` character, and the `*` in yours means any number of /s.  Mine replaces `/` followed by one or more other characters with `""`.

Comment: have you checked [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) ?

Comment: or even `separate()` from `tidyr` package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use sub:

```
x<-"2014/15"
sub("/.*","",x)
[1] "2014"
```

In your case

```
gsub ("/.*", "", admissions$Year)
```

Comment: Hey! Both of them work but it turns it into a time series! And i would like to keep it as a data frame!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr` assuming that the first 4 characters are always `year`

```
admissions$Year <- substr(admissions$Year, 1, 4)
```